# How to add custom message box

Tags: iphone

I am new to the iPhone. After running my application if I click a menu button I would like it to display About or Help, just like an alert message. If they select the about it will open the a webpage.  When help is selected it will display some text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *slpp=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong!" message:@" your message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

write code to add `UIAlertView` to your menu button click and implement delegate method of `UIAlertView`.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // write your code here
}
```